# Reference request: Scattering from action

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism, scattering, variational-principle

Consider a separable solution to a [Hamilton-Jacobi equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation#Mathematical_formulation) of an $n$-dimensional autonomous system of the form
$$W(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n,x^1,...,x^n) = \sum_j \int_0^{x^j} w^j(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n,x'^j) {\rm d}x'^j \,,$$
where $\alpha_i$ are some separation constants (integrals of motion) and $x^j$ the (generalized) spatial coordinates. I will also assume that the constants are ordered so that the constant value of the Hamiltonian or energy is the $n$-th separation constant $\alpha_n$.

The [Maupertuis action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis%27s_principle) of the system along a curve $\gamma$ reads
$$S_{\rm M}(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)[\gamma] \equiv \int_\gamma \frac{\partial W}{\partial x^j} {\rm d} x^j  = \sum_j \int^{x_{\rm i}^j}_{x_{\rm f}^j} w^j(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n,x^j) {\rm d}x^j \,, $$ 
where $x_{\rm i}^j,x_{\rm f}^j$ are the initial and final coordinates of the trajectory.

Now consider a scattering problem, where, say $x^1$ goes through an interval such as $(-\infty,\infty)$, and we want to figure out how do the other coordinates evolve during that scattering process given initial conditions and a set of constants of motion. In other words, we are given $x_{\rm i}^j$ for $j=2,...,n$, all of the $\alpha_j$, and $x^1_{\rm i},x^1_{\rm f}$; we are supposed to work out $x_{\rm f}^j$ for $j=2,...,n$.

It turns out that the complete set of equations that needs to be worked out for this scattering problem is simply given as
$$\frac{\partial S_{\rm M}}{\partial \alpha_i} = 0\,;\,{i = 1,...,n-1}$$
(The value of $\partial S_{\rm M}/\partial \alpha_n$ is simply the total elapsed time during the scattering.)

---

Now I have not found this trick in any of the usual references (Goldstein, Arnold), even though it is pretty elementary. Could you recommend references where this trick is used and/or discussed in more depth? I would also be interested in applications where the solution to the Hamilton-Jacobi equation is *not* in separable form.